# Safari Only: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, cache-control

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Works great in Chrome.

Safari returns:

`Failed to load resource: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151. Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

I have tried ajaxSetup beforeSend to null the "Cache-Control" to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried changing the req to `https` instead of `http`? This helped me just yesterday but I deleted my cache and cant find the mozilla doc I read.  I will try to find it and post it

found  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: That was it. Such a simple little thing. Thank you. All their examples in their api use the http version, just copied and paste. Can't believe I spent three hours on an 's'.

Comment: same. glad it helped!